# Как правильно изменять по падежам названия учреждений, начинающиеся с аббревиатуры...и изменять ли?

Tags: орфография, сокращения, названия

Доброго времени суток, друзья! Прочитала сегодня: "Победитель конкурса учитель года - Ф.И.О. - учитель истории МБОУ ШеломковскОЙ СОШ". Мне кажется, само название "Шеломковская" изменять не нужно, поскольку мы изменяем слова, которые сокращены (муниципального бюджетного общеобразовательного учреждения). Или я не права?

Comment: @Павлова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Или я не права?

Вы правы. Только добавьте кавычки:

*...**учитель истории МБОУ "Шеломковская СОШ"**...*

============================================

См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EC%E1%EE%F3 :

[image]

Comment: Спасибо! Распечатаю и повешу на стенд, чтобы работникам управления образования (!) стало, наконец, стыдно за то, как они подписывают грамоты, дипломы, сертификаты... (вот прям рядом с тем, что прочитала и повешу :))